# Jquery Mobile ListView design

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have written a simple listView here's the result :[image]

But it doesn't look right. This is the result that I want to have for example:
[image]

Here's my code :
html:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Players</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" id="artiste"></ul>    
    </div>

</div>
```

js +jquery:

```
function querySuccess(tx, results){
    var len = results.rows.length;
    var dataset= results.rows;

    $("#artiste").empty();

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){
        item = dataset.item(i);

        $("#artiste").append( "<li data-theme='c' data-name='"+item['firstName']+"'><a  rel='external' href='game.html'><img src='images/avatar.jpg'><h3>"+item['firstName']+"</h3></a></li>" );

    } 


    $('#artiste').children('li').on('click', function (){
        alert('Selected Name=' + $(this).attr('data-name'));
    });  

}
```

I can't understand why I'm getting this result any idea please ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Where is the code to wait for jquery and jquery mobile to load? That is a problem. See JQM docs on that under 'events'. In cases like these,  the rendered html from JavaScript will also help you solve these kinds of problems. (eg Firebug)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brief explanation of whats happening. JQM is basically styling the content before you are appending your listview items. You have tell JQM to refresh the widget you just added content to.
After you append items to the listview you have to run a `listview('refresh');` So in your case after your for loop is finished run this:

```
$("#artiste").listview('refresh');
```

Comment: I think you also have some html errors. I did test this and yes it does work.

Comment: when i put $("#artiste").listview('refresh'); i don't get all the records only the first one